# stuck in the 2nd if statement javascript

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

can anyone figure out whats wrong with my code! I want a password validation in the  third if statement. but it seems that Im just stuck with my 2nd If statement! I've been on it for hours.. dont know what went wrong! help PLS!and by the way im using onkeyup event.

```
function validateTextbox () {
    var user = document.getElementById("username"),
    pass = document.getElementById('password'),
    cpass = document.getElementById('cpassword'),
    message = document.getElementById('confirmMessage'),
    goodColor = "#66cc66",
    badColor = "#ff6666";

    //(first if statement) if its false its gonna output
    //Username must be 6 characters  if true its gonna
    //proceed to 2nd statement
    if (user.value.length >= 6) {
        //(2nd if statement) if its false its gonna output
        //password must be 8 characters  if true its gonna
        //proceed to 3rd statement
        if(pass.value.length >= 8){
            //And it does not validate password matched
            //I dont know what went wrong
            if (pass.value == cpass.value) {
                cpass.style.backgroundColor = badColor;
                message.style.color = goodColor;
                message.innerHTML = "Passwords match"
            } else {
                cpass.style.backgroundColor = goodColor;
                message.style.color = badColor;
                message.innerHTML = "Passwords does not match!"
            }
        } else {
            pass.style.backgroundColor = badColor;
            message.style.color = badColor;
            message.innerHTML = "Password must be 8 characters"
        }
    } else {
        user.style.backgroundColor = badColor;
        message.style.color = badColor;
        message.innerHTML = "Username must be 6 characters"
    }
}
```

Comment: define "stuck". WHat happens? ANy errors in your browser console?

Comment: no errors actually, but the message.innerhtml is stuck on "password must be 8 characters".It supposed to move on the next if statement if the character is 8 or more.

Comment: A script cannot be "stuck". If the code within the if statement is not executed, it is not reached in the first place. This means: your check is jsut enver true.

Comment: can you alert pass.value.length since this seems to be causing the issue

Comment: @MoussaKhalil well thanks to you! I've got an idea to solve this,because I alert all my input I found out that my HTML has the problem. I changed my HTML, I thought i should only declare onkeyup once. and I found out that I can also declare it to my password input! thanks

Comment: Anytime, and I strongly suggest you pick up jquery :)

Comment: @MoussaKhalil ohhh yeah... but right now its my first week using javascript, css, php basic stuff, Im gonna go after jquerywhen Im done with my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Code sample below just does exactly what you've explained you want. Copy and paste it on a fresh, new HTML File and then test it to see what you get. And by the way; it is not so much different from your own code, anyways....

```
    <script>
        function validateTextbox(){
            var user        = document.getElementById("username");
            var pass        = document.getElementById('password');
            var cpass       = document.getElementById('cpassword');
            var message     = document.getElementById('confirmMessage');
            var goodColor   = "#66cc66";
            var badColor    = "#ff6666";

            //(first if statement) if its false its gonna output
            //Username must be 6 characters  if true its gonna
            //proceed to 2nd statement
            if(user.value.length >= 6){
                //(2nd if statement) if its false its gonna output
                //password must be 8 characters  if true its gonna
                //proceed to 3rd statement

                if(pass.value.length >= 8){
                    //And it does not validate password matched
                    //I dont know what went wrong
                    if(pass.value == cpass.value){
                        cpass.style.backgroundColor = badColor;
                        message.style.color         = goodColor;
                        message.innerHTML           = "Passwords match"
                    }else{
                        cpass.style.backgroundColor = goodColor;
                        message.style.color         = badColor;
                        message.innerHTML           = "Passwords does not match!"
                    }
                }else{
                    pass.style.backgroundColor      = badColor;
                    message.style.color             = badColor;
                    message.innerHTML               = "Password must be 8 characters"
                }
            }else{
                user.style.backgroundColor          = badColor;
                message.style.color                 = badColor;
                message.innerHTML                   = "Username must be 6 characters"
            }
            return false;
        }
    </script>


    <form method="post" onsubmit="return validateTextbox();">
        <div id="confirmMessage"></div>
        <input type="text"      id="username"   name="username" /> <br />
        <input type="password"  id="password"   name="password" /> <br />
        <input type="password"  id="cpassword"  name="cpassword" /> <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    </form>
```

Test it [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/5p2jf3te/2/)

Comment: Thought so as well, but it's just bad indention. It's the closing curly brace from the function definition in the first line.

Comment: (There is a pending edit that fixes indention - wait until it got approved and it should be clear)

Comment: @JohannesH.   Yes.... You are right.... Just cross-checked and it turns out like you said to be an indentation issue...  could see it the first time... Thanks, though ;-)

Comment: I have arranged it the way you did, but I dont see any additional curly braces misplaced. elaborate more.

Comment: @ProblematicSolution   You can test the it here .... https://jsfiddle.net/5p2jf3te/

Comment: @Poiz Im using onkeyup event. the problem is that I only declared it once in my HTML, as in fact I should also declare it to all the input that I want to validate! thanks!